# Jquery Animate effect to move div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to be able to add an animation to this simple query for when the div is transitioned to its new position.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="left-side-bar">
        <div class="long blue" id="1">
            1
        </div>
        <div class="short red" id="2">
            2
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class='middle-side-bar'>
        <div class='long green' id="3">
            3
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class='right-side-bar'>
        <div class='short yellow' id="4">
            4
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

the CSS

```
.left-side-bar{
    clear: both;
    width: 32%;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 1%;
    margin-bottom: 100px;

}

.middle-side-bar{
    width: 32%;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    margin: 1% 0 1% 1.6%;
}

.right-side-bar{
    width: 32%;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;    
    margin: 1% 0 1% 1.6%;
}

.green {
    background-color: green;
}

.long {
    height: 300px;
}

.short {
    height: 200px;
}

.red {
    background-color: red;

}

.blue {
    background-color: blue;
}

.yellow {
    background-color:  yellow;
}
```

Basically I want the div to be moved to its new place as an animated transition, rather than have it simply appear.

here is the jsfiddle 
[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/aeyg89rd/2/)

Comment: where are they supposed to move? you mean on page load where #2 replaces #4?

Comment: once the width of screen changes but i haven't added that yet ..

Comment: You mean something like (just as example) this? http://jsfiddle.net/4b0868ft/

Comment: it s good , can you use the replace method with this ?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the replaceWith method does not work with animate in jQuery. Instead, you will probably need to find an alternative method to your solution. Here's one that slowly transitions the red box on top of the yellow box... http://jsfiddle.net/aeyg89rd/4/

I added the following jQuery, note that I used offset() to get the left and top properties of the yellow box, then I moved the red box to those left and top positions using animate() :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var num4 = $("#4").offset();
    $("#2").animate({ top: num4.top, left: num4.left }, 1000);
});
```

And I changed some CSS attributes for .red class so that I can move it around with the jQuery code above. More specifically, I changed its position to absolute, and gave it a width dimension:

```
.red {
    position: absolute;
    top: 320px;
    background-color: red;
    width: 150px;
}
```